# Get HTTPS padlock when typing in domain name directly without www

Tags: google, wordpress, cpanel

I am currently having a problem with my website's HTTPS.
I already configured in my WordPress admin to force SSL and display the HTTPS on my website link.

When I tried to enter `https://wwww.example.com` in my browser's search engine the green padlock comes out.

But when I use `example.com` the green padlock doesn't show up.

This is the image of my problem:

[image]

[image]

Whether the user enters `example.com` or `https://www.example.com` the green padlock must show up.

Comment: You would need to install a certificate for example.com also.

Comment: Do both of those URL's resolve as your home page? In other words, does non-www redirect to www version?

Comment: I already installed the certificate and in addition the picture shown above is the same site but when i tried to search the site with https://www the https shows up but when i tried  without https://www. the green padlock doesn't shows. i am thinking that i need to configure without www. but how can i do that?

Answer (score 3):

> I already configured in my WordPress admin to force SSL

Well, WordPress doesn't appear to be holding up its end of the bargain; SSL is not being "forced".

**UPDATE:** Actually, if this is the setting I think you are referring to: "Always use HTTPS while in the admin panel." - then this only applies to the "admin panel", not your main website.

Your second screenshot is showing `http://example.com` (not HTTPS) - that's why you aren't seeing the *green* padlock! You'll see the same if you explicitly type `http://example.com`. The browser simply doesn't show the protocol when requesting HTTP (port 80).

You need to issue a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS (which is what you are expecting WordPress to do for you). (You should also be redirecting non-www to www, or vice versa, whichever is canonical.)

However, it is more efficient to do this in `.htaccess` anyway, rather than let WordPress (ie. PHP) do this.

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file (before the WordPress front-controller):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This assumes the SSL cert is installed on your server and you aren't using an SSL front-end proxy.

---

**UPDATE:** To combine this with a non-www to www redirect (as mentioned above) then modify the above to read:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This assumes you have no other subdomains, other than `www`. And states... for all requests that are not HTTPS *or* where the host does not start "www." then redirect to the canonical protocol+domain.

Comment: Thanks for an informative answer. This helps me where to start do you have additional links or tutorial for this kind of problem. I also noticed that the other one is not https that is why the greenpad lock doesnt show up.

Comment: If you are referring to the "force SSL" setting in the admin panel that I think you are referring to then this only applies to the admin panel, not the rest of your site - so this explains why WordPress is not doing this for you. The code above is a standard HTTP to HTTPS redirect that any site would need to implement when moving to HTTPS (this isn't specific to WP) - sorry, I don't have a specific reference, but there's not really that more to it (providing your site already works OK on HTTPS). If you want, then you can also implement HSTS as @Avineshwar suggests - but that is an "extra".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the certificate is already in place, what you're looking is called HSTS. That's what you want for your WordPress. Now, the above post shows one way to do it.

You can also do it by sending appropriate headers so that the browser understands that any kind of request has to be served over https only.

That would be to go to your theme's functions.php page and add something like this:

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'strict_transport_security' );
/**
* This enables the HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) header.
*
* 
*/
function strict_transport_security() {

header( 'Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400' );

}
```

As a heads up, that's a short age but you can adjust that accordingly.

Refer to this [OWASP HSTS Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Note that implementing HSTS is an "extra", it is not an alternative to implementing a _redirect_ (which you mention is "one way to do it"). You should still issue a redirect when you implement HSTS. Also note that HSTS makes HTTPS more "permanent" - there's no going back to HTTP within the `max-age` period - so HSTS should only be implemented as a final stage when everything is tested.